# How to create image getting URL from JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-image

I have an app that retrieves data from [json](/questions/tagged/json), including the URL of the image I want to display in my app.

How exactly do I create an image with that URL?

I've been searching the web and found some third-party libraries ([Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) & [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)) but I was hoping there was a way to do it without those libraries.

Comment: It is strongly recommended to use third party library like Glide, Picasso, Volly etc. because it enhance your application performance by providing image caching which also saves user internet data. If you will not use this then you have to manage these thing yourself and also have to download image from URL prior to setting image to your imageview.

Answer (score 2):

It is **strongly** recommended third-party libraries (I prefer Picasso). It is more that just downloading the image. Functionalities like local storage to avoid unnecessary data transfer are too good to ignore, also complex enough to create from scratch... 
But if you still want to do it manually try this:

```
URL url = new URL("www.yourimagepathgoeshere.com");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

If you also need JSON parser, try JSONSimple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it by downloading the image from its url and then making Bitmap of the saved image path and then setting it to your imageview using:-

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(yourBitmap);
```

> But, i will prefer you to use the 3rd party libraries instead for this
>   purpose as they manages everything efficiently from downloading of
>   images in multiple threads to Bitmap Handling for memory efficient
>   implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is use picasso or glide libraries.

But u can try this Accepted Answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33496493/6333971)

Comment: picasso has a perfect integration with URL to image. you can even choose the crop type or limits or zoomable functions to expand the frame after.

Comment: Picasso
                                    .with(getContext())
                                    .load("URL AS STRING")
                                    .into(IMAGEVIEW VARIABLE);
and boom you have it :)